# How to deal with duplicate anonymous type member conflicts?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I am creating an anonymous type and I have conflicting field names.

The following code is failing because **i.Name** and **i.Target.Name** both have a property with the same name; "Name".

How do I get around this ?  Here is the code:

```
i => new
{
    i.Name,
    i.Target.Name,
    i.EndDate,
    i.LastUpdated
};
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Name the anonymous fields, as such:

```
new {Name = i.Name, targetName = i.Target.Name, ... };
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 i => new
      {
          i.Name,
          TargetName = i.Target.Name,
          i.EndDate,
          i.LastUpdated
        });
```